# Why is this throwing the wrong result?

Tags: php, count

So further to a previous question, I've updated my code to the following

```
          $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(id) FROM activities WHERE userId = ? AND status = ? AND DATEDIFF('$date', next_due) >= 1");
          $stmt->bind_param("ss", $userId, $status);
          $stmt->execute();
          $stmt->store_result();
          $numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
          echo $numrows;
```

It no longer throws an error, but returns $numrows as 1, however I know the number of rows returned should be 2 (I know it should be 2 as I have 2 identical rows in the table for testing purposes).  I've tried `SELECT count(*)`, but that also throw a 1 at me.

Comment: Use [`fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) (which returns you the result of your query) instead of `num_rows()` (which returns you the number of rows in the resulted **array**, not in your DB).

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT()` will always return 1 row. 
either select the result content or use `select id....` and then `$stmt->num_rows` on the full query

Answer (score 0):

This will return number of rows

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(id) FROM activities WHERE userId = ? AND status = ? AND DATEDIFF('$date', next_due) >= 1");
$stmt->bindParam('ss', $userId, $status);
$stmt->execute();
$numrows = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. In the end I went with the following;

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM activities WHERE userId = ? AND status = ? AND last_completed != ? AND DATEDIFF(?, next_due) >= 1");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $userId, $status, $null, $date);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
      echo $result->num_rows;
          ?>
```